# torsocks[30239]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied

Tags: tor, smb, torsocks

I want to open a shared folder at home for me to access at work, because most ftp is blocked by firewall I though I'd find an inventive way to access my files.
On my remote host (at home) I host a tor hidden service that will forward all traffic to port 445 (SMB).

On my workstation I want to connect to this SMB-files by using this command:

`torsocks smbclient -L \\address.onion -p<port#> -N`

But this seems to return following warning:

> WARNING torsocks[30239]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:186)
>
> Connection to address.onion failed (Error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)

But I can't seem to figure out what causes this error, nor do I know how to fix this.

Please help thanks ;)